# Facebook Social Graph API: "Annoying or Abusive" Error Message

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I got the following exception from the Social Graph API:

> (OAuthException) Block! You are engaging in behavior that may be
>   considered annoying or abusive by other users.: You have been blocked
>   from Body of an error/warning message. Title is: Block! You are
>   engaging in behavior that may be considered annoying or abusive by
>   other users. because you repeatedly misused this feature. This block
>   will last anywhere from a few hours to a few days. When you are
>   allowed to reuse this feature, please proceed with caution. Further
>   misuse may result in your account being permanently disabled. For
>   further information, please visit our {= FAQ page}.

My program makes thousands of calls, but the call that threw the exception was like this:

> graph.facebook.com/search?q=6511+club&access_token=...

I'm not writing anything back to the API, so I don't see how I could be violating any abuse/annoyance rules.  At first I thought I might have gone over the rate limit but [this thread](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=56950) says the exception message for that would look like this:

> Facebook.GraphAPIError: (#613) Calls to stream have exceeded the rate of 600 calls per 600 seconds.

My program is calling the above Event search endpoint with a new value for the q parameter repeatedly.  For each event returned, my program:

1. (calls /eventId) Gets the Event detail
2. (calls /pageId) Get place Page of the Event's location if the Event's location references a Facebook place Page
3. (calls /eventId/attending) Get the ids of the User profiles who are attending or maybe attending
4. (calls /?ids=...) Get the User profiles of the Users who are attending or maybe attending.

I'm using the [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com).  All my calls include an access token (from my personal User profile).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not your app which is blocked, it's your user which is blocked. Your user was identified by Facebook's automated system as a bot (which it really is actually). Next step - your user will be banned from Facebook. You're making too many calls harvesting data from Facebook by a single user. You need to rethink your app purpose and whther you need to call this data to store or your users can get it on demand from the API. Most offensive calls here are /eventId/attending and ids per each event. Call it thousand times on thousand events and the user will be blocked.